# Delete array of size 1

Tags: c++, memory-management

This is possibly a candidate for a one-line answer. I would like know it anyway..

I am writing a simple circular buffer and for some reasons that are not important for the question I need to implement it using an array of doubles. In fact I have not investiated other ways to do it, but since an array is required anyway I have not spent much time on looking for alternatives.

```
template<typename T>
class CircularBuffer
{
public:
    CircularBuffer(unsigned int size);
    ~CircularBuffer();
    void Resize(unsigned int new_size);
    ...
private:
    T* buffer;
    unsigned int buffer_size;
};
```

Since I need to have the buffer dynamically sized the buffer_size is neither `const` nor a template parameter. Now the question:

During construction and in function `Resize(int)` I only require the size to be at least one, although a buffer of size one is effectively no longer a buffer. Of course using a simple double instead would be more appropriate but anyway.

Now when deleting the internal buffer in the destructor - or in function resize for that matter - I need to delete the allocated memory. Question is, how? First candidate is of course `delete[] buffer;` but then again, if I have allocated a buffer of size one, that is if the pointer was aquired with `buffer = new T[0]`, is it still appropriate to call `delete[]` on the pointer or do I need to call `delete buffer;` (without brackets) ?

Thanks,
Arne

Comment: Actually I've always wondered why C++ doesn't define `new T`; as `new T[1];` as it would simplify the deletion. My only guess is that it is for optimization reasons (the compiler wouldn't have to create a one-step loop when calling the destructor).

Comment: @Victor Sehr: Doing so would restrict the user to parameterless constructors for type T.

Comment: It would make the deletion more complex, as you would have to use delete [].

Comment: @sharptooth: what do you mean?
@Neil Butterworth: If anything, it would make deletion more simple as only one form of delete is needed.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: Using `new[]` requires that type has a default constructor. Implementing `new` through `new[]` would enforce that requirement on all classes you use `new` on.

Comment: @sharptooth: you could still create it as `T val = new T(arg0...);`, and the compiler allocates with something like malloc(sizeof(T)) and runs the placement new on the adress. This only regard the destructor, and the compiler could handle the destruction of a `new T` as it would handle a `new T[1];`

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: Don't you see how much fine print is in such design?

Comment: To but it simply: why doesn't C++ implement the deletion/destruction of an object allocated as `new T;`, as it would handle deletion\destruction as an object allocated as `new T[1];` ?

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499895/whats-the-purpose-of-having-a-separate-operator-new/2500544#2500544

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you allocate the memory with `new T[x]`, you always delete it with `delete[]`, even if x ≤ 1.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use a vector?

Comment: +1 That's the most sensible answer to all such questions: Simply avoid manual memory management altogether. What does it buy you over a `std::vector`?

Comment: Well, as I said I do *need* to use an array. This is because I need to integrate with some code that uses pointers to certain elements for monitoring and I need to guarantee that for example the most recent elment stays at the same memory address during the lifetime of the CircularBuffer object.

Comment: @Arne: you have that guarantee if you don't change your vector.  You also don't have that guarantee if you reallocate your array.

Comment: @stefaanv I just realized that issue myself, but thanks anyway.

Comment: this would be more helpful as a comment. It's a perfectly good suggestion, but it doesn't answer his question

Comment: It actually does answer his question, as std::vector must _contain_ an array. (contiguous element requirement).

Answer (score 5):

Only use `delete[]` on addresses returned by `new[]` - regardless of the buffer size. Using `delete` in this case is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

buffer of size 1 should be allocated as `buffer = new T[1]`  and then `delete[] buffer` should be used. No need to differentiate as n =1 as special case.
**Thumb rule :**: every `new []` should have corresponding `delete []`

Answer (score 0):

When you use "delete[]" it knows that it must delete an array of objects - it calls **each** destructor of the objects in the array. Do not slip away from the standard - it will only give you *a lot* of headaches. When using new use delete. When using new [] use delete []. Just as simple as  that.